# Issues ascending and descending table columns

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I am having an issue with ascending and descending my table columns. On a table header click I should be able to sort by ascending and descending as much as I want but this code seems to be limiting me to one click.

jsfiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mu7t4e4y/5/)**

***jQuery***

```
(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "filter": false,
        "order": [
        [0, "desc"]
    ]
});
})();

$('#dtSelect').change(function () {
var searchInput = $("#searchInput");

if ($(this).val() == "0") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(1):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(1):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "1") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(2):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(2):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "2") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "3") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "4") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "5") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

});

$('#dtSelect').change(function () {
    var column = $(this).val();
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    if (column !== "") {
        oTable.fnSort([
            [column, 'asc']
        ]);
    }
});

$('th:nth-child(1):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(0).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(2):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(1).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(3):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(2).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(4):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(3).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(5):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(4).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(6):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(5).change();
});
```

When I remove some of the code I am able to sort by ascending and descending as much as I want. This leads me to believe that because I have 2 change events in the code above that maybe they are interfering with each other.

jsfiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mu7t4e4y/7/)**

***jQuery***

```
(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "filter": false,
        "order": [
        [0, "desc"]
    ]
});
})();

$('#dtSelect').change(function () {
var searchInput = $("#searchInput");

if ($(this).val() == "0") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(1):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(1):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "1") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(2):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(2):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "2") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "3") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "4") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

    else if ($(this).val() == "5") {

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
        $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
}

});

$('#dtSelect').change(function () {
    var column = $(this).val();
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    if (column !== "") {
        oTable.fnSort([
            [column, 'asc']
        ]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the default sorting as 'desc', but this bit of code is *always* sorting 'asc' which is why the click only works once.

```
oTable.fnSort([
    [column, 'asc']
]);
```

Once it's sorted 'asc', clicking it again tries to sort 'asc' again, hence no change.

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/mu7t4e4y/8/) for a working version.

**UPDATE**

Based on comments from OP -  Instead of always sorting 'asc', you need to get the current column's sort direction and sort by the opposite, and for this you can use `fnSettings().aaSorting`. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/mu7t4e4y/11/)

```
var currentDir = oTable.fnSettings().aaSorting[0][1] == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
```

This line is creating a variable called currentDir based on the current column's sort order - if it's 'asc' then `currentDir = 'asc'`, otherwise `currentDir = 'desc'`

Comment: I am still unable to sort by ascending and descending. It is now only allowing ascending sort.

Comment: If that is indeed the issue do you have any suggestions as to how I could make 'asc' a variable that says 'if asc make desc on next click and vice versa'

Comment: sorry that jsfiddle link didn't work for some reason - try it now.

Comment: Its works but now the other functionality is broken. When I click the 'th' the corresponding select option should be selected and when the select option is selected the corresponding 'th' should be selected. Also the search needs to work as well. Sorry should have noted that in the questions.

Comment: Awesome one thing though. Could u explain what the var you added does exactly (var currentDir = oTable.fnSettings().aaSorting[0][1] == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';). I am trying to make it always start on 'asc' whenever I move to a new 'th'. (note: in my acctual code the first col starts on 'asc' on load)

Comment: Have added explanation to answer. To set all the cols as 'desc', you need to add to the initialisation code: `[0, "desc"],[1, "desc"], etc`.